# How do I instantiate an ActiveRecord model from a cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, activerecord

I'm adding caching to my Rails app and one of the things I'm doing is instantiating an ActiveRecord model using the `.new` method (instead of `.create`) so it doesn't try to create a new row.

For example, if I add this to my model:

```
def from_json(json)
  o = self.new
  ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(json).each do |k, v|
    # NOTE: I am doing this instead of sending all the params to .new
    #       because Rails won't let me bulk update protected attributes
    o.send(k + '=', v)
  end
  o
end
```

And then instantiate an object from the cache:

```
o = Foo.from_json(redis.get(key))
```

Everything seems to work well until I try to change a field:

```
o.bar = "spam and eggs"
o.save
```

I get an exception saying that this is a duplicate entry.

How do I tell ActiveRecord that this actual refers to the row that already exists in the database so that it updates that row instead of throwing and exception?

Comment: It's really difficult to understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers I needed were found in `lib/active_record/base.rb`. I need to initialize the object with `new_record` set to `false` and the way to do this was to allocate the object and then initialize it with `init_with`. Note that you need to properly serialize the special `serialized_attributes` using their defined coders.

Note that I am using Rail 3.1.

```
def serialize_for_cache
  h = self.attributes.clone
  self.class.serialized_attributes.each do |key, coder|
    h[key] = coder.dump(h[key])
  end
  ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(h)
end

def deserialize_from_cache(json)
  self.allocate.init_with('attributes' => ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(json))
end
```